# In a Ruby on Rails installation, what is causing webrick to be outdated and why `gem i webrick` can update it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a new Mac computer and installed rails on it, and then I tried out the command

```
gem outdated
```

for some reason, it showed one of the gems outdated:

```
webrick (1.4.2 < 1.6.0)
```

I wonder why it is outdated on the first installed, and when I did

```
sudo gem install webrick
```

it actually installed 1.6.0 onto the system.  Doesn't it require `gem update` instead of `install` to update something?  How come `install` also updated it?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly, `gem install GEM_NAME` will install the last version available if you don't specify a version when installing, and you can have more than 1 version of the same gem on your machine.

you can run `gem environment`, and check where gems are installed, go to that folder and you will see both version gems folder there.

so when you create a rails project for example and add a specific version of a gem in the `gemfile` and another version on another project, you can have both without problems

Comment: I was thinking maybe the Rails installation didn't install any webrick, but it actually is the one that came with Ruby...

Comment: yes, you have the one from rails installation and another one when you tried with gem install webrick